# Traverse XML Style Sitemap File in C#

Tags: c#, xml, sitemap

All I'm trying to do is take my MySite.sitemap file, suck all the nodes out of it, and print it to a file. The long term goal is to take each node and see if it's a parent or a child.

### MySite.sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0">
    <siteMapNode title="Grand Parent 1" roles="Grand Parent Role" description="A simple description that I might want to write to the text file.">
        <siteMapNode title="Parent" description="" roles="Parent Role">
            <siteMapNode title="Child 1" url="linkToPage.aspx" description="A short description." />
            <siteMapNode title="Child 2" url="linkToPage2.aspx" description="Another short description." />
        </siteMapNode>
        <siteMapNode title="Parent 2" description="" roles="Parent Role" />
            <siteMapNode title="Child 3" url="linkToPage3.aspx" description"A short description." />
            <siteMapNode title="Child 4" url="linkToPage4.aspx" description="Another short description." />
        </siteMapNode>
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

### C#

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("debugFile.txt");

file.WriteLine("Sitemap File: " + pathToSiteMapFile + siteMapFile);
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(pathToSiteMapFile + siteMapFile);
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
//manager.AddNamespace("s", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
XmlNodeList nodeList = xml.SelectNodes("/siteMap/siteMapNode", manager);

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList) {
    file.WriteLine("Trying to loop through xnlist...\r\n");
    file.WriteLine("Node: " + node.InnerText + "\r\n");
}

foreach (string str in testPages) {
    file.Write("File: " + str + "\r\n");
}
file.WriteLine("The foreach loop should have wrote all the nodes in here.\r\n");
file.Close();
```

If someone can help me figure that out the next question is once I have each node enumerated will I be able to *enter* each node and do logic based on what's within each node? IE node a has roles where as node b does not.

Comment: Do you want all the `siteMapNode` nodes or just the top level ones?

Comment: `siteMapNode` as of right now, but preferably all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use [`SelectNodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d271ytdx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you need to explicitly specify both the namespace (not the namespace *prefix* from the XML file) and the name:

```
        XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xml.NameTable);
        ns.AddNamespace("myPrefix", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0");

        var topNodes = xml.SelectNodes("/myPrefix:siteMap/myPrefix:siteMapNode", ns);
        var allNodes = xml.SelectNodes("//myPrefix:siteMapNode", ns);
```

Here the text `"myPrefix"` in the query string is a lookup into the namespace added with the call to `ns.AddNamespace("myPrefix", ...)`.  It's just a lookup into the local table that you yourself created.

To output all the nodes to a file, you could do something like:

```
        foreach (XmlNode node in allNodes)
        {
            var text = new string(' ', node.AncestorsAndSelf().Count() - 1) + "Node: " + string.Join(", ", node.Attributes.Cast<XmlAttribute>().Select(a => a.Name + ": " + a.Value).ToArray());
            file.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

Given the [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class XmlNodeExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<XmlNode> AncestorsAndSelf(this XmlNode node)
    {
        for (; node != null; node = node.ParentNode)
            yield return node;
    }
}
```

Which produces output like:

> ```
>  Node: title: Grand Parent 1, roles: Grand Parent Role, description: A simple description that I might want to write to the text file.
>    Node: title: Parent, description: , roles: Parent Role
>     Node: title: Child 1, url: linkToPage.aspx, description: A short description.
>     Node: title: Child 2, url: linkToPage2.aspx, description: Another short description.
>    Node: title: Parent 2, description: , roles: Parent Role
>     Node: title: Child 3, url: linkToPage3.aspx, description: A short description.
>     Node: title: Child 4, url: linkToPage4.aspx, description: Another short description.
> ```

Incidentally, the initial query looks a lot simpler using [Linq-to-XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx):

```
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(pathToSiteMapFile + siteMapFile);

        var topElements = xDoc.Root.Elements(xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace + "siteMapNode");
        var allElements = xDoc.Root.Descendants(xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace + "siteMapNode");
```

Comment: Kind of embarrassing but, how do I know what my *prefix* is? Or is that pretty much whatever I want? I could put in "myPrefix" like your example and it'd work...?

Comment: @gh0st - use any prefix you want, just make sure the prefix you pass to `AddNamespace` is the same as the prefix you use in your query string.  I suspect Microsoft designed its API so we couldn't hardcode the prefix from the XML file and so must use the actual namespace.

Comment: Using your advice, the loop at least runs now. But still does not print out the `node.InnerText`. I'd like to at least be able to get the URL out of the node.

Comment: @gh0st - these nodes have no text values; just attributes and children.  What do you want to see in your file?

Comment: Is it possible I can pull the `title` and `url` out of them? For example in my original question I have a node with `title="Child 1"`, is it possible for me to extract that and print it to my debugFile? Or the URL field, or all of it?